# Unable to filter events in event viewer

Tags: windows, windows-8, event-viewer

Unable to filter events in event viewer: appropriate controls are dimmed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you filter the current log, you always filter the log, so the **By source** radio button is disabled.

Maybe you want to create a new **Custom View**:

[image]